# Rails 5: correct permissions for database.yml in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5

I am running my rails app on an EC2 instance server now i want to put the correct permission for the file database.yml. for security reasons
this are my permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy 3034 Jan  6 19:23 database.yml
```

also, Is there another important file that i must be careful with? thanks.

Comment: Why is it world-readable? Your database password is in there.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing your Rails app needs is read permission for the user (`deploy`).  So your perms in this limited case should be `-r-------`.  Remember that the user in the Rails app will be the child process spawned by your webserver, so make sure to configure that to dispatch Rails request as the user (and group) you define, in this case `deploy` and `deploy`.

Look at [`secrets.yml`](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/encrypted-rails-secrets-on-rails-5.1) and [Heroku's 12-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) ideas for securing your app (Rails, or otherwise).